# Passing Id value from a parent page to popup on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement of passing the Id of the parent page to the pop-up form, so that when a user clicks the 'CANCEL' button on the pop-up the control gets transferred back to the parent page.

For this, I need to have the Id of the original page in context. This page has a custom button which when clicked opens up a pop-up.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code that opens up a pop-up...

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/js/functions.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/ui/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/postmessage/jquery.ba-postmessage.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/bbq/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js')} 
requireCssFile('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css'); 


function requireCssFile(filename) 
{ 
var fileref = document.createElement('link'); 
fileref.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet'); 
fileref.setAttribute('type', 'text/css'); 
fileref.setAttribute('href', filename); 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref); 
} 


var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/Add_address")}'; 

var j$modalDialog = j$('<div id="opppopup"></div>') 
.html('<iframe id="iframeContentId" src="' + iframe_url + '" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" />') 
.dialog({ 
autoOpen: false, 
title: 'Add Details', 
resizable: true, 
width: 800, 
height: 540, 
autoResize: true, 
modal: true, 
draggable: true 
}); 

j$modalDialog.dialog('open');
```

Here is the VF page:

```
    <apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup">

         <apex:pageBlockSection >
         <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputlabel for="Address_Line1">
            Address Line 1
            </apex:outputlabel>
            <apex:panelGroup >

            <apex:inputtext id="Address_Line1" value="{!AddrLine1}" required="true"/>


                            <apex:pageBlockSection >
         <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputlabel for="Country">
            Country
            </apex:outputlabel>
            <apex:panelGroup >

            <apex:inputText id="Country" value="{!Country}" required="true"/>

            </apex:panelGroup>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>


            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" onclick="window.close();">

            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="abcd">

            </apex:commandButton>

  </apex:outputPanel>
```

The user after entering Address Line 1 and the country fields can either click CANCEL or SAVE buttons.

Comment: Are you talking about the html id?

Comment: I am talking about the default salesforce Ids

Comment: Is your popup also another visualforce page?

Comment: the pop-up is a javascript that calls a visualforce page

Comment: So at the place where you call the popup link, add the id as a query string and use it in the popup. Can you edit the question and add the code where you call the popup

Comment: var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/Add_address)}';       here Add_address calls my VF page. This statement is added in the javascript to open the pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values by using the query string.

```
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR(/apex/Add_address?parent_id=your_parent_page_id)}';
```

And then in the popup page controller constructor, grab the id like below

```
String ppId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('parent_id');
```

Comment: I tried this..But because the pop-up opens on the same page so the redirecting to the parent page does not happen

Comment: What you mean by redirecting here?if it's a popup, just closing the popup(may be upon clicking cancel as you have mentioned) user will automatically land into the parent page right?btw,this answer is for your question "how to pass is to popup page"

Comment: When the user clicks on 'Cancel' nothing is happening as of now. :( i want to redirect to the page on which the button was originally clicked to open the popup.

Comment: if you need to close the popup and let user land into the parent page, add `top.close();` into the onclick event of your cancel button. No need to purposely redirect.

Comment: top.close() isn't working...

Comment: If you don't have any script breaks and put it in the correct place it should work. anyway the discussion is deviating the original question. We could discuss this in a chat if you had enough reputation(20) for that.